# Field Adjunction

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was a bit confused with what $F(a, b, y, \dotsc)$ means. The book assumes that $F$ is a subfield of $E$.

> If $a, b, y, \dotsc$ are elements of $E$, then by $F(a, b, y, \dotsc)$ we shall mean
>   the set of elements in $E$ which can be expressed as quotients of polynomials
>   in $a, b, y, \dotsc$ with coefficients in $F$. It is clear that $F(a, b, y,\dotsc)$ is a field and is the smallest extension of $F$ which contains the elements $a, b, y, \dotsc$ . We shall call $F(a, b, y, \dotsc)$ the field obtained after the adjunction of the elements $a, b, y, \dotsc$ to $F$, or the field generated out of $F$ by the elements $a, b, y, \dotsc$ .

So are the elements $a, b, y, \dotsc$ polynomials? Also I'm not sure what "quotients of polynomials **in** $a, b, y, \dotsc$" means. What do they mean by "in"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [Tex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) and a blockquote. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that $x \in F(a_1, a_2, \ldots)$ iff for some $n$ there are polynomials $P, Q \in F[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$ with coefficients in $F$, such that $x = \frac{P(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)}{Q(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)}$.

Comment: So are $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ variables or coefficients?

Comment: $P(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ is a value of a polynomial $P \in F[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ for argument $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$. For instance, $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, because for $P(x) = 1, R(x) = 1 + x$, we have $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}} = \frac{P(\sqrt{2})}{R(\sqrt{2})}$

Comment: @Artus The book omits the *essential* condition that the denominator polynomial must evaluate nonzero (else, e.g. as in prior comment with $\,R(x) = x^2\!-\!2\,$ we deduce $\,a = 1/0\:\Rightarrow\:0 = 0\cdot a = 1\:$ in the field, contra field axioms).

Comment: @MathGems: this condition is not necessary. No element is of the form $\frac{P(a_1, \ldots, a_n)}{Q(a_1, \ldots, a_n)}$ where $Q(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = 0$, because this expression does not make sense.

Comment: @xyzzyz Saying it "does not make sense" is simply an informal way of saying what I said. In any case, to be rigorous, any definition needs to imply this, one way or another. The point is that while $\rm\:F[a,b,c]\:$ is the image of the *polynomial* ring $\rm\:F[x,y,z]\:$ evaluated at $\rm\:(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)\:$ this does not generalize to *rational "function"* fields $\rm\,F(x,y,z)\,$ because the denominator may evaluate to $0.\ $

Comment: @MathGems: sure, but the quoted definition just does not require to mention this. It all depends on wording.

Comment: If you make that informal definition *formal*, then it will be necessary. It may seem like nitpicking, but it is important *conceptually* because it reflects a major difference between polynomial rings vs. their quotient fields (rational "functions"), viz. that polynomials can always be evaluated (their universal mapping property), which fails for rational functions.

Comment: @xyzzyz I'm a bit confused. Why doesn't it make sense to say $Q(a_1, a_2, ... , a_n)=0$? What if the polynomial equals zero when we substitute those numbers? Why can't that happen?

Comment: @Artus: it's not $Q(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = 0$ that does not make sense, it's $\frac{P(a_1, \ldots, a_n)}{Q(a_1, \ldots, a_n)}$ that does not make sense when $Q(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = 0$.

Comment: @MathGems: let's not nitpick the potential errors that could be made, but currently aren't, shall we?